# How to sort data using http in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-http

I'm following heroes tutorial, and this is  `the code` so far, I want to add a sorting methods to sort data by age.

Comment: The plunk attached shows an empty project. Please post the correct link.

Comment: @PhaniRahulSivalenka try again: https://plnkr.co/edit/YHzyzm6ZXt4ESr76mNuB?p=preview

Comment: Cool works now!

Comment: You should post a minimal reproducible example in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an array using array's [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control) function.

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => {
    if ( a.name < b.name )
        return -1;
    if ( a.name > b.name )
        return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

or in your case if you comparing numbers

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => a.age - b.age);
```